# XSD: define 2 elements with the same name but exact definition of attributes

Tags: xml, xsd

Is there a way to define several attributes with fixed values and subelements for 2 elements with the same name?

```
<Root>

  <element 
    attributeA="1" 
    attributeB="2">
    <subElement/>
  </element>

  <element 
    attributeA="3" 
    attributeB="4">
    <subElement/>
  </element>

 </Root>
```

I want any of this elements to be possible but the following element NOT to be allowed:

```
<element 
   attributeA="1" 
   attributeB="4">
   <subElement/>
</element>
```

I know in xsd it is not possible to have 2 elements with the same name under one "parent".
to create only on element and restrict it via enumeration does not seem to work since I have to avoid "mixed" forms. 
The names of the elements have to identical and they have to have the parent element.

Is there a solution I don't see or a workaround for this problem?

Comment: how are you implementing the validation? .net? Java? which is the host program? or is it just browser?

Answer (score 2):

Such a model would violate the constraint "Element Declarations Consistent", which requires that if two element particles in a content model have the same name then they must have the same type.

You can do it in XSD 1.1, of course, using assertions.